# How to generate PKCS7 format signature using IOS iphone SDK?

Tags: ios, ios4, openssl, pkcs#7

I could Generate PKCS1 formatted raw signature.. and was able to verify it even. 
But could not find the resource to generate PCKS7 Formatted Signature using IPHONE IOS SDK.

I need to sign a simple text message.

Which library I have to use?

Can we use openssl for this? if yes? then how to include it in the XCODE library framework?

Pls help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use openssl for this, however you will need to compile it yourself and link your App against the static library.  If you want to run it in both the iPhone Simulator and a real iPhone Device (you do), you'll need to create a 'fat' library containing both armv7 and i386 architecture code.  If you want to support iPhone 3 instead then you'll need to include armv6 architecture code.  It's best therefore to build the library with all 3 architectures.

Here's a couple of resources that describe how to build openssl for iOS:

http://atastypixel.com/blog/easy-inclusion-of-openssl-into-iphone-app-projects/
https://github.com/st3fan/ios-openssl

**EDIT**:  I actually modified st3fan's build script, which I have pasted here:

[setenv.sh](http://pastebin.com/94RaeqX6) and [build_openssl.sh](http://pastebin.com/fxEnLzZe)

Download these scripts and keep them somewhere like ~/bin (review them and then `chmod` them 0755 once you are sure they are not malicious).

Next edit `setenv.sh` as it assumes there is a directory where you will install your 3rd-party libraries.  By default this is `/opt/local/ioslibs` so make sure that exists and is owned by you else the final bit will fail.  It's been configured for Xcode 4.2/iOS SDK 5 using the default locations so that might need correcting too.

`build_openssl.sh` is configured to build a specific version of openssl (1.0.0e) and will download the source tarball if it's not in the current directory (you need `wget` for that, but if you cannot be bothered to install `wget` then manually download it using the link within the script).  When you run it, it will build the library in armv6, armv7 and i386 arch's and copy the correct files to the installation directory.

Comment: I did as per the link "easy inclusion of openssl .." but the lybcrypto.a file from openssl.xcodeproj shows in red colour. and the 

#import <Openssl/ssl.h> is not recognized. xcode not able to file Openssl ?

Comment: I have editted my answer with the way I successfully built openssl.

Comment: Please note: I have updated the `setenv.sh` script to fix the `$CFLAGS` definition as I was experimenting with it while trying to get the libcurl to compile (which I have not succeeded at yet).

Comment: Hi trojanfoe,

I have integrated the openssl project to my project.. and xcode is able to recognize the openssl library files.

I need to generate PKCS7 formatted Sha256 Signatures.
Can you please help me out with few examples using
Pkcs7_sign() method

importantly for Sha-256 Digest. Please

Comment: @chetan Sorry I didn't see your comment; if you want to get the attention of someone then start the comment with `@username` and they will be notified.

Comment: @chetan , did you solve this problem ? I don't know how to generate PKCS7 , too. I can compile with openssl in the Xcode now. If you solved the problem , let me know how to generate Pkcs7 . Thanks

Comment: hi @saturngod , which version of iOS are you working on, coz...
building PKCS7 structure is possible only with OpenSSL (in conjuction with iOS 3.X.X, as Apple doesnt provide creation of PKCS7..just the PKCS1(RAW Signature). because what I experimented was...OpenSSL can only be compiled with GCC complier but not with LLVM..

Right from iOS 4.0.1...the default compiler is LLVM

Comment: @chetan : Could you please share code to generate  PKCS7. I am able to integrate openssl. I just need the code to use below method. PKCS7 *PKCS7_sign(X509 *signcert, EVP_PKEY *pkey, STACK_OF(X509) *certs,
      BIO *data, int flags)